# how to get mainactivity.this in contentProvider class - in android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-context

I am writing a content provider in android. I want to write query implementation. I am creating a DbHelper object in the query function of contentProvider. But I am getting error when I create this that is I cannot access MainActivity.this in this content provider class. I need that MainActivity.this so that I can initialize DbHelper and use already implemented function query in DbHelper class by me. How do I solve this problem?

Code:

```
public class CourseContentProvider extends ContentProvider {


    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri arg0, String[] arg1, String arg2, String[] arg3,
            String arg4) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (sURIMatcher.match(arg0)==COURSE) {
            MyDbHelper obj = new MyDbHelper(MainActivity.this);//Error msg here: No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope
        }
        return null;
    }
//other auto generated functions
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: show you code and show where the error is because i bet you dont need to do what you want

Comment: As always, if you are new to SQLite in Android, try to check some tips here http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get `Context` just call `getContext()` in your class that extends `ContentProvider`

**example:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        Context context = getContext();
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return (db == null) ? false : true;
    }
```

Comment: It solves the problem but does not answer the question!

Comment: @coyer yes it does, he needs context and I showed how to get it. If you are trying to actually use and `activity` in your contentprovider you are using it ver very wrong